# How to loop function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, loops

I have this code. I need advice on how to loop a function in jQuery.
Is my function written correctly?
I am using jquery and jquery ui for this project the function works, but only once. Is there a function in jquery that would solve my problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
var nr1 =$('.nr1'), nr2 = $('.nr2'), nr3 = $('.nr3'), nr4 = $('.nr4'), nr5 = $('.nr5');
  
  
  
  
 function animation_slider() 
 {
  nr1.addClass('acttive').fadeIn(800).delay(2000).animate({left: 1920, opacity: 0}, 1200, function()
   {
    nr1.removeClass('acttive', function()
    {
      nr2.css({top: -350}).addClass('acttive').fadeIn(800).delay(2000).effect('fold', 'easeOutQuad', 1200, function()
       {
       nr2.removeClass('acttive', function()
         {
         nr3.css({top: -350}).addClass('acttive').fadeIn(800).delay(2000).effect('blind', 'easeOutQuad', 1200, function()
           {
             nr3.removeClass('acttive', function()
             {
               nr4.css({top: -350}).addClass('acttive').fadeIn(800).delay(2000).effect('clip', 'easeOutQuad', 1200, function()
               {
                 nr4.removeClass('acttive', function()
                 {
                   nr5.css({top: -350}).addClass('acttive').fadeIn(800).delay(2000).animate({left: -1920, opacity: 0}, 1800, function()
                   {
                     nr5.removeClass('acttive');
                   });
                 });
               });
             });
           }); 
         });
       });
     });
   });
 };
animation_slider();//How to loop this function?
});
```

```css
div.slider-container{
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #424242;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.obrazy-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
img.obraz {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
img.obraz.nr1.acttive {
  opacity: 1; 
}
img.obraz.nr2.acttive {
  opacity: 1; 
}img.obraz.nr3.acttive {
  opacity: 1; 
}
img.obraz.nr4.acttive {
  opacity: 1; 
}
img.obraz.nr5.acttive {
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-section">
            <div class="slider-container">
              <div class="obrazy-container">
              <img src="http://test.warrior.ayz.pl/images/1.png" class="obraz nr1">
              <img src="http://test.warrior.ayz.pl/images/2.png" class="obraz nr2">
              <img src="http://test.warrior.ayz.pl/images/3.png" class="obraz nr3">
              <img src="http://test.warrior.ayz.pl/images/4.png" class="obraz nr4">
              <img src="http://test.warrior.ayz.pl/images/5.png" class="obraz nr5">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I am asking for advice on how to loop `function animation_slider();` ?
I tried loops "for" "while" "do while" unfortunately they don't work in jQuery.
Is there any other option?

Comment: did you try jquery each?  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Ok i'll try to read that documentation article. Maybe today. i have to read very carefuly because i'm Polish but English is my second language.

**Thank you**

Comment: Any time you find yourself creating variables like `nr1`, `nr2`, etc. you should be using an array, not separate variables. It will simplify your code so you don't have to repeat everything.

Comment: i'll keep that in mind.

Comment: What is the desired behavior of this code? Could you please describe what you want to achieve more precisely?

Comment: This code supouse to be a slider. every thing is working fine but only once.

Comment: When i try to do something like this: `for( var i = 0; i < 999; i++)
{
  animationion_slider();
};` 
doesn't work.

Anyway I decided to get rid of jQuery and write my own simple library.
More programming but every thing wil work as I want to.